# creating a worksheet using gspread

Tags: python, gspread

I am new to python. I was just trying to create a google worksheet using gspread. I read about using google api's from [here](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html). I downloaded credentials from [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=spreadsheet-1995) which is a file in json format. Then I used this code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials =     ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('spreadsheet1995.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
worksheet = gc.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows="100", cols="20")
```

But it throws an error `'Client' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'` although I read documentation which included this attribute. Here is the [link](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html) which I followed. Please help me sort out this problem.

Answer (score 16):

First, you need to know to the difference between a *spreadsheet* and a *worksheet*. A spreadsheet is a container of worksheets. Like a book with many pages.

If you go to Google Sheets and hit the big "+" button you will start a new a new *spreadsheet*. This spreadsheet will at first contain a single worksheet named "Sheet1". You may add more worksheets to your spreadsheet.

Now back to [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/) and your code sample.

To create a worksheet you need a spreadsheet. This is what you're missing in your code.

Skipping the authentication part, you code should look like this:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = gc.open("The name of your spreadsheet")
worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows="100", cols="20")
```

Now with `worksheet` you may read cell values, edit them, etc.

[gspread API Reference](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Use:
spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows="100", cols="20")
Instead of:
gc.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows="100", cols="20")

Comment: How do you use the `import_csv` function for a worksheet? How do you add content from scratch in the worksheet?